# Exclude Objects from getting dropped

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a pl/sql code which accepts schema name as input1 and stored in variable l_schema_name and objects that needs to be excluding from getting dropped to input2 and stored in variable l_exclude_objects (default is NULL and if multiple objects are passed seperated by comma)

Below is the code block which i have in my code but somehow it is not excluding objects passed while running the script.

```
FOR i IN (
    SELECT owner, object_type, object_name
    FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner = l_schema_name
    AND    object_type IN ('SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'TRIGGER', 'MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'TABLE', 'VIEW', 'SYNONYM', 'FUNCTION', 'TYPE', 'PROGRAM')
    AND    (l_exclude_objects IS NULL OR object_name NOT IN
           (SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(l_exclude_objects, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
            FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(l_exclude_objects, ',') + 1))
    ORDER BY DECODE(object_type, 'TRIGGER', 1, 'PACKAGE', 2, 'PROCEDURE', 3, 'FUNCTION', 4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM', 6, 'MATERIALIZED VIEW', 7, 'TABLE', 8, 'SEQUENCE', 9)
)
```

Tried but no success

Answer (score 0):

It actually *works*:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_schema_name      VARCHAR2 (20) := 'SCOTT';
  3     l_exclude_objects  VARCHAR2 (30) := 'TABLE,VIEW,FUNCTION';
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i
  6        IN (  SELECT owner, object_type, object_name
  7                FROM all_objects
  8               WHERE     owner = l_schema_name
  9                     AND object_type IN ('SEQUENCE',
 10                                         'PROCEDURE',
 11                                         'PACKAGE',
 12                                         'TRIGGER',
 13                                         'MATERIALIZED VIEW',
 14                                         'TABLE',
 15                                         'VIEW',
 16                                         'SYNONYM',
 17                                         'FUNCTION',
 18                                         'TYPE',
 19                                         'PROGRAM')
 20                     AND (   l_exclude_objects IS NULL
 21                          OR object_type NOT IN
 22                                (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_exclude_objects,
 23                                                                 '[^,]+',
 24                                                                 1,
 25                                                                 LEVEL))
 26                                       FROM DUAL
 27                                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 28                                            REGEXP_COUNT (l_exclude_objects, ',') + 1))
 29            ORDER BY DECODE (object_type,
 30                             'TRIGGER', 1,
 31                             'PACKAGE', 2,
 32                             'PROCEDURE', 3,
 33                             'FUNCTION', 4,
 34                             'VIEW', 5,
 35                             'SYNONYM', 6,
 36                             'MATERIALIZED VIEW', 7,
 37                             'TABLE', 8,
 38                             'SEQUENCE', 9))
 39     LOOP
 40        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.object_type || ' ' || i.object_name);
 41     END LOOP;
 42  END;
 43  /
TRIGGER DOB_CHECK
TRIGGER HIRE_DATE_CHECK
PACKAGE PKG_TEST
PROCEDURE LIST_LOG
PROCEDURE P_FETCH
PROCEDURE LIORBYBRANCH
PROCEDURE GETTORIMBYDOCTOR
PROCEDURE P_EMPTY
MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV
TYPE PATRIK_SPLIT_VALUE
TYPE T_ROW
TYPE PATRIK_SPLIT_TABLE
TYPE TABLE_INVOICE
TYPE INVOICE_DATA_TABLE
TYPE T_TAB

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, where's the catch? In line #21.

- if l_exclude_objects contains object **type**, it should've been `object_type` you're checking
- if it contains object **names**, then check `object_name`

My previous example presumes it is the *type*.

But OK, let's try names. This is Scott sample schema and it contains `EMP` and `DEPT` tables, and they are excluded from the output:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_schema_name      VARCHAR2 (20) := 'SCOTT';
  3     l_exclude_objects  VARCHAR2 (30) := 'EMP,DEPT, BONUS';
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i
  6        IN (  SELECT owner, object_type, object_name
  7                FROM all_objects
  8               WHERE     owner = l_schema_name
  9                     AND object_type IN ('SEQUENCE',
 10                                         'PROCEDURE',
 11                                         'PACKAGE',
 12                                         'TRIGGER',
 13                                         'MATERIALIZED VIEW',
 14                                         'TABLE',
 15                                         'VIEW',
 16                                         'SYNONYM',
 17                                         'FUNCTION',
 18                                         'TYPE',
 19                                         'PROGRAM')
 20                     AND (   l_exclude_objects IS NULL
 21                          OR object_name NOT IN
 22                                (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_exclude_objects,
 23                                                                 '[^,]+',
 24                                                                 1,
 25                                                                 LEVEL))
 26                                       FROM DUAL
 27                                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 28                                            REGEXP_COUNT (l_exclude_objects, ',') + 1))
 29            ORDER BY DECODE (object_type,
 30                             'TRIGGER', 1,
 31                             'PACKAGE', 2,
 32                             'PROCEDURE', 3,
 33                             'FUNCTION', 4,
 34                             'VIEW', 5,
 35                             'SYNONYM', 6,
 36                             'MATERIALIZED VIEW', 7,
 37                             'TABLE', 8,
 38                             'SEQUENCE', 9))
 39     LOOP
 40        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.object_type || ' ' || i.object_name);
 41     END LOOP;
 42  END;
 43  /
TRIGGER DOB_CHECK
TRIGGER HIRE_DATE_CHECK
PACKAGE PKG_TEST
PROCEDURE LIST_LOG
PROCEDURE P_FETCH
PROCEDURE LIORBYBRANCH
PROCEDURE GETTORIMBYDOCTOR
PROCEDURE P_EMPTY
FUNCTION F_TEST
FUNCTION COL_MAX_LENGTH
FUNCTION ABC
FUNCTION PATRIK_SPLIT_CLOB
VIEW V_TEST
VIEW V_EMP_20
MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV
TABLE TABLE_B
TABLE STATUS
TABLE EMPLOYEE
TABLE TEST
TABLE SALGRADE
TABLE TABLE1
TABLE TABLE2
TABLE TEMP_20230509_PARENT_MV
TABLE RUPD$_TEMP_20230509_PARENT
TABLE MLOG$_TEMP_20230509_PARENT
TABLE TABLE_A
TABLE MSG
TABLE DEPARTMENT
TABLE EMP1
TABLE STAFF
TABLE DEMO_EMPLOYEE
TABLE ACTIVITY_HISTORY
TABLE ORDERS
TABLE EMPLOYEES
TABLE TEMP
TABLE TEMP_20230509_CHILD
TABLE USER_TABLE
TABLE NEW_TABLE
TABLE TEMP_20230509_PARENT
TYPE PATRIK_SPLIT_VALUE
TYPE PATRIK_SPLIT_TABLE
TYPE TABLE_INVOICE
TYPE INVOICE_DATA_TABLE
TYPE T_TAB
TYPE T_ROW

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, I'd say it seems to be OK.